# spring test \ Junit - skip configuration on tests

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have the following class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableScheduling
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {

config.enableStompBrokerRelay(
                  "/topic",
                  "/queue/");
config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}


@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

registry.addEndpoint(
             "/wsdemo").withSockJS();
}
```

}

I would like to be able to **NOT** configure the class above whenever I'm running tests. is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A plain Junit test (without the spring runner) will ensure the class is not configured. you can then use mock objects (see Mockito) to satisfy any dependencies.

Comment: So which bit of the class do you want to not be configured?

Comment: not helpful - you've said you need the spring runner, presumably to provide some config. You can always supply a different application-context,xml file for this test, with the relevant piece of config omitted or changed. Does this help?

Comment: Yeah i know, i wanted to avoid using 2 different xmls where in one i dont scan the specific config file. i thought there is a more straight forward way.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - are you trying to test an error condition, or something like that?

Comment: No, I just happen to have websockets in my project. and my junit tests DO NOT test the websocket infrustructure at all. but i get some weird error message from the websocket stomp broker in my tests. thats why i want to avoid tunrining the websocket configuration off whenever i am running junit tests.

Comment: Really sounds like you need either a separate config xml for these tests, or if you're doing true unit testing, provide mocks for the objects you're not directly testing. Not sure there's more I can do to assist.

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate "application-context.xml" for your tests, then there you must have directive:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="...">
...
</context:component-scan>
```

Modify it as below:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="...">
...
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="{package}.WebSocketConfig"/>
</context:component-scan>
```